# If RAM Disk had continuous power, even if the computer was turned off, would it still be volatile?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ramdisk

I am planning to host a Minecraft server and discovered RAM Disks. They are fast, but volatile(meaning if it lost power, then it would lose all data). I am a tinkerer myself so I thought, "Maybe I can build a memory slot adapter with a button cell hooked up to it with a transistor that hooks up to the motherboard's power, so if the computer turns on, the button cell power would be cut off." Would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically it would. Some commercial products even have this feature. However, I don't think you'll get very far with a button cell since a DDR3 memory module typically draws 2-3 Watts. You would probably do better to experiment with a bigger battery pack and a decent DC-DC converter.

That said, for your application I think two or three SSD drives in RAID0 would be a much better solution and would provide more than enough IOPS.

Comment: Worlds fastest answerer ladies and gentlemen.

Comment: Not only would the SSDs themselves likely provide enough I/O performance (both throughput and IOPS) and are already persistent storage by their very design, but the operating system (unless totally braindead) should prime the cache with the data as it is being used, meaning that once the data has been accessed once or a few times, it'll be in RAM anyway.

Comment: Yes, it might be better since you can make the 3 SSDs into a dynamic drive.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate "solution" I've seen is to set up a mirror of RAM disks where at least one leg of the mirror is on a different computer (exported with iSCSI or similar)

It's still volatile, and you'll lose your data if all the computers goes down, but it's slightly more secure than just a RAM disk.

Probably not safe for production use :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check SSDs over PCIE

http://ocz.com/consumer/pci-express-ssd

Speeds are like 1400MB/s